# CSharpCodeProvider Output console app as windows form app

Tags: c#, .net

I have some code to create an exe from c# source on-the-fly using the CSharpCodeProvider, here it is:

```
public static void BuildAssembly(string code)
{
    Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider provider =
    new CSharpCodeProvider();
    ICodeCompiler compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();
    CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters();

    compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
    compilerparams.GenerateExecutable = true;
    compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = false;
    compilerparams.OutputAssembly = @"C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\test.exe";
    CompilerResults results =
       compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);
    if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
    {
        StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
        foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
        {
            errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n",
                   error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
        }
        throw new Exception(errors.ToString());
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

all works fine, it compiles my console application c# code. But when I'm writing a console app and i requires that the console not be visible I simply go to the application properties and change output type from console to Windows Application. So how would I do this via the function I pasted above? I've looked through all the options but .. no idea :(

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
compilerparams.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe";
```